# Find number of function satisfying given condition,

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinations

> Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. $A,B,C$ be non null subsets of $S$. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$, $g: B\rightarrow C$ and $h$ be the composite function defined from $A$ to $C$ such that $h(x)=g(f(x))$ and $h(x)$ is bijective function. Find number of such function h(x).

**Solution Given in book:**

For $h(x)$ to be bijective $n(A)=n(B)=n(C)$.

**My doubt:**

I think for $h(x)$ to be bijective it is not necessary that $n(A)=n(B)=n(C)$. According to me $n(A)=n(C)$ and $n(B)$ can be greater than or equal to $n(A)$ or $n(C)$.

**Please Help me.**

(Where $n(X)$ denotes number of elements in set $X$)

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @user376343 Then is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the solution in the book?

Comment: As the problem is formulated, it seems they ask for the number of bijections from A to C. The number of ways "ABC" isn't important.

Comment: In book they considered f is bijective and g is also bijective. But f need not be bijective and g need not to be bijective. Forget about solution in book is there any way to solve this stated problem without considering f and g to be bijective but h to be bijective? or is it a long case work?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the number of bijections from $A$ to $C$.

Clearly, we need $n(A)=n(C)$.

Suppose we fix $n(A)=k$, we can pick $A$ in $\binom{5}{k}$ way and we can pick $C$ in $\binom{5}{k}$ way.  Having pick $A$ and $C$, we have $k!$ way to define their mapping.

Hence the number of bijections from $A$ to $C$ is $\sum_{k=1}^5 k! \binom{5}{k}^2$.

---

Now the question is whether this is the solution that we are looking for. We have to prove for every such bijection, we can find a set $B$ and functions $f$ and $g$ such that $h(x)=g(f(x))$.

We just let $B=A$ and $f$ be identity and $h$ be $g$ to illustrate that.

Of course, the choice of $f, g, B$ are not unique.